# Comparing object methods leads to different results in 3.8

Tags: python, comparison, python-3.7, equality, python-3.8

Consider this simple class:

```
class A:
    def method(self): pass
    def __eq__(self, other): return True
```

Now if I create two instances of the class and compare their `'method'` attributes, I get different results in Python 3.7 and 3.8:

```
meth1 = A().method
meth2 = A().method
print(meth1 == meth2)  # True in 3.7, False in 3.8
```

What's going on here? Why are the methods equal in 3.7 but not in 3.8? And what does this have to do with `__eq__`?

Comment: It has nothing to do with `A`'s `__eq__` method. You are comparing two function objects. The fact that `==` returns True/False in different versions is just a Python implementation-specific thing of `function.__eq__`.

Comment: @YevhenKuzmovych what do you mean? i think the OP's understanding is correct and the behaviour puzzling

Comment: @Chris_Rands I mean that `__eq__` method in the `A` class does not influence that. It's the function class' `__eq__` method (`A.method.__eq__`) that has been changed somehow.

Comment: @YevhenKuzmovych if you remove the `__eq__` method you will get `False` in all python versions

Comment: `print(meth1 == meth2)` is not comparing thre instances though, it's comparing the (horribly-named) `method` instance methods on the instances.

Comment: @Chris_Rands Even though it is true, it is not `__eq__`'s business. Python never ensures that the `__eq__` method in the instance can be used to test the instance's methods. If it can, then it is just a bug or an implementation detail.

Comment: @Chris_Rands Aha. Didn't see that coming :). That's interesting then. It actually calls `A`'s `__eq__`. WAT?

Comment: My guess is there's an optimisation/similar that says 'if testing equality of 2 instance methods, first check if they're methods of equal/the-same instances'.

Comment: Incidentally, it's not clear to me what the expected/desired behaviour of instance-mathod-comparion should be generally - I can see arguments for True and False here.

Comment: @YevhenKuzmovych btw i agree that defining `A.__eq__` should not impact `A.method.__eq__` but apparently it does in this case. It's not actually just using `A.__eq__` though because other comparisons still return `False` e.g. `meth1 == 1`

Comment: @Chris_Rands looks like a bug to me.

Comment: @YevhenKuzmovych a bug that was fixed for python 3.8, but i can't find anything relevant in the changelog

Comment: `A.__eq__` was never (immediately) relevant. Because `A.method` is a descriptor, the result of `A().method` is not a `function` object, but the `method` object returned by `A.method.__get__(x, A)` (where `x` is the instance of `A` on which the attribute lookup occurs).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What happened is [this commit](https://github.com/python/cpython/commit/ac20e0f98d6727ba97a9575bfa2a11b2f6247c35) based on [issue 16171610](https://bugs.python.org/issue1617161) (and [this discussion on python-dev](https://mail.python.org/pipermail/python-dev/2018-June/153959.html)).

With these (selected) comments:

> It seems unlogical to me that whether or not the instance methods of two different instances are equal or not depends on the equality of the instance.

followed by

> All in all I think that this part was an accident
>   and never designed;

and

> I think it makes little sense that the equality test for the instance
>   methods takes the equality of the instances into account. Imho, this
>   behaviour is inconsistent with the principle of no surprises. The
>   correct behaviour (again imho of course) is that instance methods only
>   compare equal to the same instance method of the same instance, where 
>   'same instance' is based on 'is' not on '=='.

and

> This change can be considered as a bugfix, but since it can break the user code (unlikely), it may be safer to merge it only in 3.8 and expose as a new feature.

So this seems to be considered a bugfix/feature because bound methods should only be equal if they are bound on the same instance, not if the instances are considered equal. In Python <= 3.7 the bound method equality calls the equivalent of `instance1 == instance2` (thus calling your `__eq__`) of the instance while in Python 3.8 it checks if `instance1 is instance2`.

---

The corresponding changelog item can be found in [section "Python 3.8.0 alpha 1"](https://docs.python.org/3.8/whatsnew/changelog.html#python-3-8-0-alpha-1) - it's a long list of items, so I included a copy here:

> - [bpo-1617161](https://bugs.python.org/issue1617161): The hash of `BuiltinMethodType` instances (methods of built-in classes) now depends on the hash of the identity of *__self__* instead of its value. The hash and equality of `ModuleType` and `MethodWrapperType` instances (methods of user-defined classes and some methods of built-in classes like `str.__add__`) now depend on the hash and equality of the identity of *__self__* instead of its value. `MethodWrapperType` instances no longer support ordering.

Comment: That discussion on python-dev was really interesting, thanks for this excellent and enlightening answer :-)